# Sorting A LL using Merge Sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, mergesort

I am trying to sort a Linked List using mergesort in Java. However, I am not getting the sorted Linked List as output. This is the code:-

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
        if(head==null||head.next==null){
            return head;
        }
        ListNode middle = findMiddle(head);
        ListNode rightHead = middle.next;
        middle.next = null;
        ListNode leftHead = head;
        leftHead = sortList(leftHead);
        rightHead = sortList(rightHead);

        return merge(leftHead,rightHead);
    }
    public ListNode merge(ListNode leftHead, ListNode rightHead){
        ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode temp = dummyHead;
        while(leftHead!=null && rightHead!=null){
            if(leftHead.val<rightHead.val){
                temp.next = leftHead;
                temp = leftHead;
                leftHead = leftHead.next;
            }else{
                temp.next = rightHead;
                temp = rightHead;
                rightHead = rightHead.next;
            }
            // temp = temp.next;
        }
        if(leftHead!=null){
            temp.next = new ListNode(leftHead.val);
            leftHead = leftHead.next;
            temp = temp.next;
            }
        else if(rightHead!=null){
            temp.next = new ListNode(rightHead.val);
            rightHead = rightHead.next;
            temp = temp.next;      
        }
        return dummyHead.next;
    }
    public ListNode findMiddle(ListNode head){
        ListNode slow = head;
        ListNode fast = head.next;
        while(fast!=null && fast.next!=null){
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```

I have used the standard mergeSort algorithm which is used to sort Arrays just the data type is changed to Linked List. There are no compiler errors so I guess something has to be wrong with my logic.

Comment: The problem source seems to be from LeetCode or other programming challenge / practice site. In my opinion, it is polite that such a question includes a link to the problem description page.

Comment: Have you tried following the code with a debugger?  What were the results?

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: *However, I am not getting the sorted Linked List as output* -- [What is a debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in the `merge` function. After the first `while` loop, you are using a `if-else` case which just merging only 1 node, but it should be merged through while loop to merge the whole remaining part.

For example : 
`left = [2, 3]` 
`right = [1]`
according to your code :
after end of while loop : `mergedList = [1]`
then `if(leftHead!=null)` satisfy. After that if condition : `mergedList = [1, 3]`
but there is still a node remaining in left part.

```
while(leftHead!=null){
    temp.next = new ListNode(leftHead.val);
    leftHead = leftHead.next;
    temp = temp.next;
}
while(rightHead!=null){
    temp.next = new ListNode(rightHead.val);
    rightHead = rightHead.next;
    temp = temp.next;      
}
```

*But*, you can use if-else too as it's a **LinkedList**. You can do as following, when you are just adding the remaining part in the end, that might save your code a little running time too.

```
if(leftHead!=null){
    temp.next = leftHead;
}
else if(rightHead!=null){
    temp.next = rightHead;     
}
```

Comment: merge should not be allocating new nodes., just re-linking existing nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The code after the main merge loop should not be allocating new nodes:

```
        if(leftHead!=null)
            temp.next = leftHead;
        else
            temp.next = rightHead;
```